# read/parse json data from socket in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js `net` tcp server, where I receive json data from the client(s). I would like to buffer it until the whole json block arrives, than maybe parse it, maybe just forward it to somewhere else. What modules are out there which are compatible with the latest node (0.6.x)?

Should be fast, and if it's pure js that's better for me.

b.

Answer (score 0):

hum, net module for buffering, JSON.parse() for parser, sorry seems obvious but...
Check out :
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
for forwarding

Comment: I know that JSON.parse() would parse my string, but what if i get in the first package this:'{"key":"val' than in the second the rest: 'ue"}'? I can't parse each of them, just the both. But It can be more complicated, If I get lot's of json strings after eachother... or http-proxy has this kind of events fired when a complete json string arrives?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this issue for quite some hours after thinking again about it and solving it with a quite easy and straight forward solution.

My application is receiving utf-8 encoded JSON data, sometimes quite large data. In the end I also had chunks of my JSON document, which I needed to complete in order to successfully parse them.

My solution is a simple String buffer variable that I fill with the incoming data as long as I will receive an "new line" aka "\n". Then I "deliver" the data to be parsed and continue filling the buffer with next messages.

My code is as follows:

```
var buffer = '';
client.on('data', function(data) {
    if (data.indexOf('\n') < 0) {
      buffer += data;
    } else {
      var msg = buffer + data.substring(0, data.indexOf('\n'));
      buffer = data.substring(data.indexOf('\n') + 1);

      console.log('Sending msg: ' + msg);
    }
}
```

This solution only works because my protocol is based on utf-8 and has '\n' as the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for your code, i solved it in a similar way. I count the number of "{" and "}" characters, and at the moment the number of "}" characters equal to the number of "{" chars I parse the string, otherwise I buffer it. I didn't upload the code here because I haven't have time to test it, and have other things to do... However for me It seems like a very common problem, I'm surprised that there isn't a general solution for this.

Comment: I figured out that I have some racing conditions on that code. Sometimes the buffer is overriden by an aditional callback. Could that be the case or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: don't know, maybe you should post a question about this on StackOverflow.